# Object clone() in Java: why does this assertion fail?

Tags: java

From what I know, object `clone()` creates a new copy of the cloned object. In my case I'm trying to clone the matrix of `Symbol` (which is a simple `enum`). `this.table` is the original object, while `t` is the clone. When I write a new value into a cell of `t` I would expect that `this.table` remains unchanged. However this is not the case and **the second** `assert` fails. (I added the first assert only to ensure the correctness of the second one).

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public State applyAction(Action action) { 
            int x = ((TickAction)action).x;
            int y = ((TickAction)action).y; 
        Symbol[][] t = this.table.clone();
        assert this.table[x][y] != currentPlayer.getSymbol();

        t[x][y] = currentPlayer.getSymbol();

        assert t[x][y] != this.table[x][y] ;

        TableState ts = new TableState(t,this.currentPlayer.getNextPlayer());
        ts.setLastAction(action);
        return ts;
    }
```

Note: with debugger I checked that `t` and `this.table` actually have different `id`, however after a second check I noticed that, despite this, their single cells have the same `id`. Then I'm much confused about this. Could someone explain me what's happening?

Comment: You don't even need an obfuscater! :p

Comment: Try adding `assert t != this.table;` as they must be different objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of arrays of `Symbol` instances.

When you call `clone()` on `this.table`, you get a new array, `t`, but each of the arrays in `t` is the same as the array in `this.table`.

In order to check that, you can try `assert t[0] == this.table[0];`.

In order to get a deeper clone, you would have to create a new array and initialize it yourself:

```
Symbol[][] t = new Symbol[][this.table.length];
for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
{
    t[i] = new Symbol[this.table[i].length];
    for (int j = 0; j < t[i].length; j++)
    {
        // Here I am sharing the Symbol objects between the two arrays.
        // If you do not want that, define your own way to copy or clone the object.
        t[i][j] = this.table[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here, but Java makes a distinction between == and .equals() and everyone gets burned once or twice using == with some object reference that actually needs .equal.  Give this a try...

```
assert this.table[((TickAction)action).x][((TickAction)action).y].equals( currentPlayer.getSymbol() );
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant use clone as is, it wont help you if you did not implemented it yourself.
same for equals(except strings)